# How did the (First Ever) Perceptron Classify Pictures?

Tags: neural-networks, classification

I was reading about the development of the original Perceptron Algorithm (i.e. the First Neural Network https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) - if I understand this correctly, a Perceptron is a One Layer and One Neuron "Neural Network".

It seems that Rosenblatt figured out how to use this **One Layer and One Neuron** Neural Network to perform binary classification on linearly separable data.

I have been trying to find a source that clearly explains the task he was trying to accomplish - for instance, the following link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Suevq-kZdIw @ 1:23) explains that he used the Perceptron to classify pictures of shapes and letters, but I have trouble understanding how this shape/letter recognition task can be considered as "linearly separable". The Perceptron took a picture of some letter or shape, and converted it into 400 entries - this was the input of the Perceptron. **I find it hard to believe that data in a 400 dimensional space can be considered as "Linearly Separable".**

I heard that AI Researchers soon discovered that the Perceptron can not not successfully handle the "X-OR" Problem (https://dev.to/jbahire/demystifying-the-xor-problem-1blk) - that is, with only a single neuron, the Perceptron can not "learn" a function of sufficient complexity to separate data, when the data is not linearly separable. This is when they figured out that adding more neurons allows the Perceptron to better handle data that is not linearly separable.

In the end - I have the following question:

- It was proven that the first Perceptron can only "work" (i.e. perfectly classify) on data that is linearly separable.
- Yet, Rosenblatt was able to use the Perceptron to successfully recognize pictures of letters and shapes.
- At the surface, "recognizing pictures of numbers and shapes" seems far more complicated than the "X-OR" Problem (I understand why "X-OR" is not linearly separable : no such straight line exists that can perfectly separate data when organized according to the "X-OR" condition).
- Thus: **Why is a seemingly complicated problem like "recognizing pictures of numbers and shapes" considered "linearly separable"?**

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems confused because it conflates related topics. Are you asking if the data used to train the perceptron was linearly separable? Or are you asking what the definition of a linear model is? Or are mistaking a model that performs "well enough" for a model that achieves perfect accuracy? Or are you assuming that every instance of a problem involving image recognition is *not* a linearly-separable problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently writing an essay and have been researching ai for a couple of weeks now so I think I can clear this up. To understand why classifying letters and symbols is considered linearly separable it helps to look a little bit closer. The perception that you mentioned that broke down an input into 400 separate pieces was not working with 400 dimensions, instead, it looked at each of the 400 sections as a pixel and determined a binary value of 1 or 0 based on the brightness of the pixel. The system then looks at which of those pixels are 1s and which are 0s and determines the letters based on the combination of pixels being turned on and pixels being turned off.

That's a bit of an oversimplification, but the actual reasoning of the system is linearly separable because the inputs can all be determined as binary values.

Comment: It's not completely clear how this answers the question, because the explanation "The system then looks at which of those pixels are 1s and which are 0s and determines the letters based on the combination of pixels being turned on and pixels being turned off" seems like a completely ordinary description of any model of image data. Perhaps you could expand on your answer to include some of the key details and citations materials you are referring to in your paper. This would help make your answer more specific and allow others to read the same materials that you are, if they're so interested.