# Did Early AI Researchers Understand Why the Perceptron "Worked"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I was reading about the development of the original Perceptron Algorithm (i.e. the First Neural Network) - if I understand this correctly, a Perceptron is a One Layer and One Neuron "Neural Network". The first perceptron was able to successfully classify pictures of shapes and letters (around 1958).

**I am interested in learning about to what extent did Early AI Researchers understand the mathematical limits and abilities of the Perceptron.** For instance, I know that many years later, an important theorem in AI called the "Universal Approximation Theorem" was established, that showed a Neural Network in "theory" could perfectly learn any function - but the earliest version of this theorem was established in 1989 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) - 30 years prior to the successful implementation of the first Perceptron.

While doing some reading online, the only theoretical results I came across that suggest early AI Researchers understood the "mathematical abilities" of the Perceptron were:

- **"X-OR" Problem**: It was theoretically demonstrated that a simple Perceptron can not perfectly separate data that is non-linearly separable.
- **Perceptron Convergence Theorem**: A theoretical result was found that suggests "a finite number of iterations are required to update the weights of the perceptron such that all data  points (provided they are linearly separable) will be perfectly classified" (https://web.mit.edu/course/other/i2course/www/vision_and_learning/perceptron_notes.pdf).

I have the following question : **Did the early AI Researchers have "confidence in the mathematical abilities" of the first Perceptron? Or was this more of a trial-and-error experiment which had no mathematical justifications as to if such an experiment was even theoretically possible - let alone in practice?**

Thanks!

Comment: On the contrary; by 1969 most researchers were convinced that perceptrons *did not and could not work* after Minksy and Papert showed that a single layer of perceptrons could not learn XOR. See for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_winter#The_abandonment_of_connectionism_in_1969) "*Mainstream research into perceptrons came to an abrupt end in 1969, when Marvin Minsky and Seymour Papert published the book Perceptrons, which was perceived as outlining the limits of what perceptrons could do*" ...

Comment: and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_artificial_intelligence#Perceptrons_and_the_attack_on_connectionism) "*An active research program into the paradigm was carried out throughout the 1960s but came to a sudden halt with the publication of Minsky and Papert's 1969 book Perceptrons. It suggested that there were severe limitations to what perceptrons could do and that Frank Rosenblatt's predictions had been grossly exaggerated. The effect of the book was devastating: virtually no research at all was done in connectionism for 10 years.*"

Comment: That sentiment seems to fit with my own perceptions a bit more than those 10 years later. When I started learning about the topic in the early 1980s, the area seemed pretty dead (there was still AI but it was mostly focused in other directions) --- though it started to pick up a few years later, after I had moved onto other things.

Comment: Thank you so much - these are very interesting comments! I posted a related question over here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562439/how-did-the-first-ever-perceptron-classify-pictures

Comment: I always wondered: how on earth could the first Perceptron successfully perform "image recognition" - a task that is generally considered to be difficult (and surely "non-linear") ... yet the first perceptron couldn't perfectly pass X-OR LOL

Comment: At least there is a clear explanation as to why the first Perceptron was mathematically unable to perfectly pass X-OR. I am still confused as to how the Perceptron could recognize pictures of shapes/letters. I was reading the Wikipedia Article about the Perceptron, and it seems like each picture of a shape or letter was converted into a "row of 400 measurements" (using a camera).  If I understood this correctly, this seems incredible! A Perceptron could classify (at what accuracy?) 400 dimensional pictures of shapes/letters so many years ago!